# Работа с сетью в делфи

Tags: сокеты, delphi, indy

Доброго времени суток, друзья! Ищу рабочие исходники, статьи по работе с сетью (передача файлов и сообщений) между клиентом и сервером-приложением. Интересны варианты как с помощью Indy компонентов (IdTCPServer, IdTCPClient) так и с помощью сокетов. Помогите пожалуйста, поделитесь наработками, советами или ссылками... Не минусуйте вопрос и не закрывайте его пожалуйста, так как последняя надежда на форумы, инет перерыл в поисках стоящей информации, не нашел: все, либо детский лепет какой-то, либо голимая теория, которую применить нельзя на практике, либо урывки кода, которые не сложить в единую программу.

Comment: Работа с сокетами клиент-серверное приложение, работа с текстом: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/Chat_Room_Socket_(Delphi)

Comment: никто не работал с делфи что ли? Делфисты откликнитесь, нужна помощь...

Comment: Работа синду компонентами: http://pro.dtn.ru/delphi-net/1-net.html

Answer (score 2):

[Delphi FAQ. Интернет и Сети](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/internet_net.html)
В качестве альтернативы indy посоветовал бы [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/), примеры работающих софтин там тоже есть.

Comment: Спасибо, Юра! Буду смотреть твои ссылки! Может кто-то еще даст советы? Друзья-эксперты отвечайте).

Comment: Предпочтение конечно отдаю лучше Инди компонентам, чем сторонним...

Answer (score 2):

```
ClentSocket.Address:='76.74.38.41'; //Указать адрес сервера
ClentSocket.Port:=7777; //Указать номер порта
ClentSocket.Active:=True; //Открыть. Готов только после OnWrite

ClentSocket.Socket.SendBuf(BufOut,4); //Передача
ClentSocket.Socket.ReceiveBuf(BufIn,Cnt+4); //Прием. Лучше использовать OnRead
```

Comment: спасибо за краткий пример!

Answer (score 1):

> инет перерыл в поисках стоящей
> информации, не нашел: все, либо
> детский лепет какой-то, либо голимая
> теория, которую применить нельзя на
> практике, либо урывки кода, которые не
> сложить в единую программу.

Уважаемый, в сети очень и очень много примеров и даже в исходниках на Delphi. 
Например, те же чаты, чего-то да стоят. Ищите на koders.com codeproject.net sourceforge.net google code и т.д. Примеров массы!

А в теории вам не будет готовых кодов, теорию надо профильтровать и опробовать, т.е. научится тому чему учит теориия. Да и теории вы наверное ни разу не видели. Если хотите посмотреть на теорию создание client-server'ного приложения. Начните с чтения документации WinSock и основ TCP/IP из RFC'ек. Вот там теория, аж мозг пухнет.